# Retain CSS :hover when changing CSS styles with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have a `div` (acting as a button) which has certain CSS that activates when hovered on:

```
#btn{
    width: 80%;
    height: 125px;
    border: 1px solid #9676E8;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: background-color 0.25s ease;
    background-color: #B299F2;
    color: white;
}

#btn:hover{
    background-color: #9676E8;
}
```

Note: `#9676E8` is a darker shade of `#B299F2`, both blue.

This button has a toggle function, where the desired effect is that clicking it will toggle its background to become red instead of blue. The relevant JavaScript is here:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    if(!toggle){
        toggle = true;
        btn.style.border = "1px solid #FF0000";
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "#AA3030";
    } else {
        toggle = false;
        btn.style.border = "1px solid #9676E8";
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "#B299F2";
    }
});
```

Note: `#AA3030` and `#FF0000` are shades of red.

My problem is that after clicking the button the first time, the button turns red (as desired). However, when clicking it so it changes back to blue, there is no more hover effect afterward. Hovering over it doesn't do anything but clicking it still works.

I do not need the button to have a hover effect while it is red, but I want to retain the hover effect while it is blue. Is there any way of doing so?

[JsFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hbecwygq/)

Comment: Set up a demo on jsfiddle or codepen and we will gladly help you solve your problems

Comment: I will suggest using a class, put the colors in a class then add and remove the class in JS toggle.

Comment: alright, working on it

Comment: @iroegbu but if I simply change the class, the transition effect won't take anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the inline rule set by JS overrides any CSS rules (unless they have the `!important` declaration). Instead of setting the color back to the same value, set it to empty to reset it:

```
else {
    toggle = false;
    btn.style.border = "";
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use classes instead of setting CSS properties in you JS it can be achieved by changing classes on toggle.

```
<!-- html -->
<div id="btn" class="blue"></div>

/* Javascript */
var toggle = false;
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    if(!toggle){
        toggle = true;
        btn.className = "red";
    } else {
        toggle = false;
        btn.className = "blue";
    }
});

/* style */
#btn{
    width: 80%;
    height: 125px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: background-color 0.25s ease;
    color: white;
}
.blue {
    border: 1px solid #9676E8;
    background-color: #B299F2;
}
.red {
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    background-color: #AA3030;
}

.blue:hover{
    background-color: #9676E8;
}
```